# Hide and show the child div based on condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a parent div with two child.When button clicks it shows only one div based on condition.

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="result_table" >
       </div>
     <div id="new">
          </div>
</div>
```

Am assigning the data to table depends on the data retrieved from the page.So i want to hide the result _table while the new table is visible.

```
$('#BUTTON').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
            url: PAGE.PHP,
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                  $("#result_table").html(data.table);
                  $("#new").html(data);
            }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check data results

```
$('#BUTTON').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
            url: PAGE.PHP,
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
               if(data.table)
               {
                   $("#result_table").show().html(data.table);
                   $("#new").hide();
               }
               else
               {
                  $("#new").show().html(data);
                  $("#result_table").hide();
               }
            }
    }); 
});
```